# How to bootstrap zero coupon rates and what is the relationship with par yields

Tags: bootstrapping, yield, zero-coupon

I understand the basic logic of bootstrapping zero coupon rates (take a bond, discount each cashflow at the prevailing/previously solved zero rate, and solve for the last rate at the last cashflow). I always thought that this was done so that the sum of the discounted cashflows equals the price of the bond in the market, but I have come across people using 'par yields' instead, which I believe are the yield on the bond if its price is 100.

Does anyone know which approach is more correct, between using the market price and YTM or using a price of 100 and the par yield? Do both approaches give the same results? (I don't really understand the point of using par yields for bootstrapping!)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are three ways to express the "yield curve": zero coupon rates, forward rates or par yields. From any of these you can find the others by an appropriate mathematical transformation.

Comment: So what is the point of using par yields to work out zero coupon rates? Wouldn't it be easier just to use the YTMs and bond prices observed in the market?

Comment: par yield and ytm are synonymous.